# Relational Algebra Cartesian Product

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I'm beginning to learn database and now i just learn relational algebra and encounter a problem. Given below table:

```
R1 = {(Jon, Smith, 24, British, Single, UK, Guitarist),
(Jon, Maynard, Smith, 74, British, Widowed, UK, Scientist),
(Jon, Travolta, 50, American, Married, USA, Plumber),
(Katy, Pierce, 23, UK, Single, Caiman Island, unknown)}
With Schema = {Name, Surname, Age, Nationality, Status, Country, Job}
```

How do i calculate R4 = R1 X R1 using self cartesian/cross operation?

Comment: Hint: `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: Is this a Relational Algebra question, or SQL? What do you think the result from the query is going to tell you/what does it mean?

Comment: Too many attribute values for the 2nd tuple.

Comment: You are not clear. Please edit to exactly explain what your "problem" is & what your question is. X *is* Cartesian/cross join. "Self join" is a general term for maybe doing some kind of attribute renaming to a table value then some kind of joining the old & new then maybe restricting then maybe projecting. What does "how do I calculate" mean? If you are trying to say something about *SQL* then you haven't said it either. Also different versions of "relational algebra" have different notions of X so you must tell us or give a link/reference to how its output looks given its input.

Answer (score 1):

try `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM R1 
CROSS JOIN R1 tab2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select from the two tables with no join

```
Select r1.*,r2.* From r1,r1 r2
```